# What options do I have when performing RAG on similarly phrased chunks?

Tags: information-retrieval, llm

I'm building a RAG pipeline to extract real estate phrases from excel documents. These phrases are short (2-5 words) and are often phrased differently.

I've manually added in different phrases to each prompt to suggest the LLM to look for them.

What else could I do? What more powerful options do I have?

- Search for each term manually? -> slow due to loads of calls
- Embed the terms in the excel doc and similarity search the embedding of 'Total Income' against those in the excel doc?

````py
# Example prompt with 4 similar terms
income = f"""What is the Total Income? 

It may also be called: 
- Total Revenue
- Effective Gross Income
- Total Operating Receipts
- Total Operating Income

Or something similar

Return a signed number or nan. Do not write anything else."""
"""
```
````